# Discord.js using ids instead of mentions?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, I've recently started developing a bot for a server that I staff in however I can't get the bot to use IDs instead of mentions.

For mentions, I have been using `message.mentions.users.map` but I don't know how I can make it so it also accepts IDs (Using ||).

If anyone could help it would be really appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for `message.mentions.users.filter(user => user.id === id)` ?

Comment: I'm trying to make it like dyno, like how you can do ?av @user#1111 and also their ID like ?av 339139393713.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to fetch the user by their id then display their avatar

Replace `<Client>` with either **bot** or **client**

(depending on what you set up your Discord Client as)

```
const target = <Client>.users.fetch('ID goes here')
message.channel.send(target.displayAvatarURL())
```

Comment: `UserManager.fetch()` returns a `Promise`, so make sure you use `async/await`